# Angular: ¿Cómo redireccionar de un modal a un input?

Tags: angular, modal, rutas, router, angular-router

¿Cómo puedo en Angular, redireccionar al hacer click en un botón que esta dentro de un modal a un input que esta dentro de un componente?

Se que la pregunta es algo confusa, pero es algo asi:

Yo tengo un modal y un dentro de este esta un botón que tiene la función de editar el campo que esta dentro de un input en un componente.

Por ejemplo tengo el modal y el botón es el que esta seleccionado en rojo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Entonces cuando le doy click ese boton, me tendria que redirigir al input donde coloque ese número

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Actualmente este el código HTML del modal

```html
<div mat-dialog-content>
  <mat-icon class="closeIcon" (click)="close()">close</mat-icon>
  <h1>Código de verificación</h1>
  <div class="d-flex jutify-content-center align-items-center container">
    <span>Hemos enviado un código de verificación al&nbsp;<strong>{{data.name}}</strong><mat-icon class="createIcon">create</mat-icon>
        </span>
  </div>

  <br>
  <div class="otp">
    <ng-otp-input #ngOtpInput (onInputChange)="onOtpChange($event)" [config]="config"></ng-otp-input>
  </div>
  <div class="buttonContainer">
  </div>
  <countdown class="buttonContainer2" [config]="{ leftTime: 15 }"></countdown>
  <div class="buttonContainer">
    <!-- <h5>¿No recibiste un código?</h5> -->
    <div *ngIf="later">
      <button type="submit" class="reenviarBtn" (click)="sendOTP()">Volver a Enviar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Y este método de aqui (esta en el componente donde esta el input al que quiero redireccionar) y su función es llamar al modal y asu vez pasarle al modal data

```
openDialog() {
        const dialogConfig = new MatDialogConfig();
        dialogConfig.disableClose = true;
        dialogConfig.autoFocus = true;
        dialogConfig.width = "30%";
        this.phone = this.patientForm.controls['phone'].value;
        // phone = this.bookingService.bookingModel.patient?.phone
        //dialogConfig.data = phone;
        //let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(OtpProcessModalComponent, {data: {cell: this.phone}});
    
        let dialogRef = this.dialog.open(OtpProcessModalComponent, {
          data: { name: this.phone },
        });
    
        dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe((valid: boolean | undefined | null) => {
          if (valid) {
           // this.phone
            // this.router.navigate(['../pagar'], { relativeTo: this._activedRoute });
            this.verifiedPhone = true;
          }
        });
      }
```

Yo supongo que no tiene que ser muy complicado de hacer, porque al final solo es un redirección, no se si hacer una suscribción para enrutar, tampoco se si es posible, por eso vengo aqui a preguntar. Tal vez alguien con mayor conocimiento me explicar, lo agradecería mucho porfavor

Saludos y gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, puedes replicar tu problema en https://stackblitz.com ? será más fácil responderte.

Comment: Cuando dices redirigir te refieres a que el campo de tipo display se transforme en un input?